# How to split a 2D array into chunks

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, datatable, split

I have a large list of data in a datatable. I extract first column and made a 1D string array of them, because I want to call a web service method which takes the first column as an input. 
I have to report the results of web service for each of these records, and I need the rest of the columns to do so. So I've converted the datatable into a 2D string array. It worked well, but now I want to change the code in a way that split the datatables into chunks of the same size and do this routine for these chunks. 
I write this code and call the web service for each chunks, but I don't know how to access the 2D string array chunks that has the same list of first columns as in 1D chunk so I can call the Result function.

here's my code:

```
if (dt0.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    WebReferenceProvisionOmc.stringArray[] noBlkRes;

    tels = dt0.AsEnumerable()
              .Select(row => row.Field<decimal>("tel_no").ToString().Substring(0, 3) + " " + row.Field<decimal>("tel_no").ToString().Substring(3))
              .ToArray();

    var tchunks = from index in Enumerable.Range(0,tels.Length)
                  group tels[index] by index/ChunkSize;

    paras = dt0.Rows
               .OfType<DataRow>()
               .Select(r => dt0.Columns
                               .OfType<DataColumn>()
                               .Select(c => r[c.ColumnName].ToString())
                               .ToArray())
               .ToArray();

    var pchunks = from ind in Enumerable.Range(0, paras.Length)
                  group paras[ind] by ind/ChunkSize;

    foreach (var c in tchunks)
    {
        noBlkRes = ws.connectBulk(c.ToArray());
        for(int j=0;j<c.ToArray().Length;j++)
        {
            Result(Convert.ToInt32(noBlkRes[j].item[1]),pchunk????);
        }
    }
}
```

and my Result function prototype is like this:

```
private static void Result(long res,string[] parameters)
```

Comment: How do you define the chuncks? wouldn't it be easier to have chuncks that are simply a few "rows" of the first dimension and all the "cells" in that row. So you split only the 1D into chuncks, not the 2D

Comment: Your data is not 2D array, it's an array of arrays (jagged array). And yes, that makes a difference.

Comment: ok how to solve my problem considering that it's an array of arrays?